# Multiple media queries causing problems in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css

I am creating a webpage which should adapt to multiple screen sizes. For this I am using css media queries in my stylesheets.

Everything works fine until I do a test in Microsoft Edge (Firefox and Chrome do what they are supposed to do). It seems like Microsoft Edge only uses the first media query.

When I remove the first media query, the second one is used...

Is this a common issue? Does anyone ran into the same problem?

I use the line for media queries: @media all and (max-height: 600px)

This is the relavant code:

```
<a href="#top" id="go-to-top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
    <nav>
        <button id="cross" class="cross menuButtonNotVisible"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        <button id="parametres" class="parametres menuButtonVisible"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
        <a href="#one">Home</a>
        <a href="#two">Wie we zijn</a>
        <a href="#three">Wat we doen</a>
        <a href="#four">Locatie</a>
        <a href="#six">Contacteer ons</a>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <h1>Mooi design. Gebruiksvriendelijk. Op alles voorzien.</h1>
        <h2>Deze website is een voorbeeld van hoe uw website eruit zou kunnen zien. Vragen?</h2>
        <h3><a href="#six">Vraag uw gratis offerte aan</a></h3>
        <div id="angle-down"><a href="#one" id="angle-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></div>
    </header>
    <div id="iconBar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#one"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i><p>Op maat</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#two"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i><p>Veiligheid</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#three"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><p>SEO</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#four"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><p>Responsive</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#six"><i class="fa fa-code"></i><p>Interactief</p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">

@media all and (max-height: 600px){
header h1{margin-top:3em;}
header h2, header h3{display:none;}
header {height:300px;}
#iconBar ul{top:300px; height:150px;}
.wrapper{top:450px;}
}
@media all and (max-width: 700px){
.noResponsiveDisplay{
display:none;
}
nav, .sticky{
background-color:#323a45;
margin:0;
padding:0 1em 3em 1em;
color:white;
display:block;
height:1.3em;
overflow:hidden;
position:fixed;
border:0px solid black;
}
nav a, .sticky a{
clear:both;
display:block;
padding:0 0 0.4em 0;
font-size:1.5em;
color:white;
}
#iconBar{
display:none;
}
header{
height:78%;
}
header h1{
margin-top:6em;
font-size:1.5em;
}
header h2{
font-size:0.8em;
}
.wrapper{
top:78%;
}
.menuButtonVisible{
display:block;
}
.mobileMenu{
overflow:visible;
display:show;
height:auto;
}
}
```

And there's a third media query below. However, this one only works if the first and second media query are removed.

Comment: Could we have all the relevant CSS, please? It may be an error in the CSS that only Edge has picked up :)

Comment: Yeah it is mostly like caused by copy pasted code, microsoft is very picky.

Comment: Your code gets my upvote.

Comment: I have put the relevant code inside my orginal question block

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with classygroundcovers.com, several things are broken in Edge because only the first is taken. Is Chrome/FF/IE you get a chat widget over 590px, in Edge you get a text link in the bottom navbar no matter what the width is.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what is your default stylesheet like if you want to tell the browser that when the width is smaller than 700px apply these styles but as soon as the height goes smaller than 600px over ride these styles with these new values. for this you need to put the media query "@media all and (max-width: 700px)" above this media query "@media all and (max-height: 600px)". I hope it will work.